# setting localStorage for multiple items

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble setting up local storage to save the textArea input for each of the time blocks. I have commented out 3 different sections where I was playing with different techniques to try and make it work. However, I was not able to set it to save the  text in local storage and get it so that it stay on the page when you revisit it. Please let me know if you can help me with a solution to fix it. I have provided a link to my repository. please look at the feature/calendar branch  because that is where my code resides.  I also snippet the code into here for you to look at. I am new to coding so please be patient with me. I am still learning the terminology and different ways to reach the objective/goal.

```js
saveBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('saveBtn');

//  creates a new instance for time and date.
const currentDay = luxon.DateTime.now().toLocaleString(luxon.DateTime.DATETIME_MED);
//  format's the date and time.
var newFormat = {
    //  The selected date format from luxon documentation.
    ...luxon.DateTime.DATETIME_MED,
    //  added the day of the week.
    weekday: 'long'
};

// creates a new instance for time and date.
const newCurrentDay = luxon.DateTime.now().toLocaleString(newFormat);
//  checks if time works.


//  creates a new instance to parse the date and time into the header html.
var ol = document.querySelector('header');
//  creates the ol element.
const list = document.createElement('ol');
//  styles the <ol> element.
list.setAttribute('style', 'color: white; background-color: black; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center;');
//  displays newCurrentDay variable in the header as readable text.
list.innerText = newCurrentDay;
//  appends the newCurrentDay variable to the ol element.
ol.appendChild(list);

//  creates an array to change the blocks bases on their time in the text area element.
const timeBlocks = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('description'));
// assigning timeBlocks based on time.
for (var i = 0; i < timeBlocks.length; i++) {
    //  gets the current hour to connect the color changing feature in the text area element based on the 24hr format.
    const now = luxon.DateTime.now().hour.toLocaleString();
    //  if statement's to change the color of the blocks based on time using the 24hr time format.
    if (timeBlocks[i].id < now) {
        timeBlocks[i].classList.add('past');
    }
    if (timeBlocks[i].id > now) {
        timeBlocks[i].classList.add('future');
    }
    if (timeBlocks[i].id === now) {
        timeBlocks[i].classList.add('present');
    }
}


// // * testing
// saveBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('saveBtn');

// var save = addEventListener('click', function () {
//     //  creates a new instance to parse the date and time into the header html. 
//     var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

//     this.window.localStorage.setItem('textarea', textarea.value);

//     this.window.localStorage.getItem('textarea');
// });




//  TODO: can  use save button for event text to persist even when refreshed.

// $('.saveBtn').on("click", function () {
//     window.localStorage.setItem('task', $(this).siblings('.description').val());
// })

// loadTask = function () {
//     return window.localStorage.getItem('task');
// }


// let taskArray = [{
//     21: "",
//     22: "",
//     23: "",
// }];

// $('.saveBtn').on("click", function () {
//     window.localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(taskArray));

//     JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('tasks'));

// var storedData = window.localStorage.getItem(taskArray);

// if (storedData) {
//     taskArray = JSON.parse(storedData);
//     alert(taskArray);
// }
// });


// TODO:  event is saved into time block using local storage


// TODO:  have my minutes actively change.
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
}

textarea {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  color: #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

.description {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.time-block {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.row {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  height: 80px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  ;
}

.hour {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-top: 1px dashed #000000;
}

.past {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: white;
}

.present {
  background-color: #ff6961;
  color: white;
}

.future {
  background-color: #77dd77;
  color: white;
}

.saveBtn {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #06AED5;
  color: white;
}

.saveBtn i:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css" />
  <title>Work Day Scheduler</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-3">Work Day Scheduler</h1>
    <p class="lead">A simple calendar app for scheduling your work day</p>
    <p id="currentDay" class="lead"></p>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Time blocks go here -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 border-top border-dark">
        9:00PM
      </div>
      <textarea class="description col-8" id="21">Event</textarea>
      <button class="btn saveBtn col-2"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 border-top border-dark">
        10:00PM
      </div>
      <textarea class="description col-8" id="22">Event</textarea>
      <button class="btn saveBtn col-2"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 border-top border-dark">
        11:00PM
      </div>
      <textarea class="description col-8" id="23">Event</textarea>
      <button class="btn saveBtn col-2"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 border-top border-dark">
        12:00AM
      </div>
      <textarea class="description col-8" id="0">Event</textarea>
      <button class="btn saveBtn col-2"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 border-top border-dark">
        1:00PM
      </div>
      <textarea class="description col-8" id="13">Event</textarea>
      <button class="btn saveBtn col-2"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 border-top border-dark">
        2:00PM
      </div>
      <textarea class="description col-8" id="14">Event</textarea>
      <button class="btn saveBtn col-2"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 border-top border-dark">
        3:00PM
      </div>
      <textarea class="description col-8" id="15">Event</textarea>
      <button class="btn saveBtn col-2"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 border-top border-dark">
        4:00PM
      </div>
      <textarea class="description col-8" id="16">Event</textarea>
      <button class="btn saveBtn col-2"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 border-top border-dark">
        5:00PM
      </div>
      <textarea class="description col-8" id="17">Event</textarea>
      <button class="btn saveBtn col-2"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
    </div> -->


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2.3.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascript/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow which of this code you are expecting to do what, so I will comment on the problems of each.

```
this.window.localStorage.getItem('textarea');
```

This line doesn't really do anything.  You're getting the value, but not using it anywhere.

```
loadTask = function () {
    return window.localStorage.getItem('task');
}
```

Nothing calls this function, so that doesn't do anything either.

```
JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
```

Again, here, you're not doing anything with the return value, so it goes nowhere.

> However, I was not able to set it to save the text in local storage and get it so that it stay on the page when you revisit it.

You need to load data out of localStorage when `DOMContentLoaded` is fired.  Use your browser's developer tools to first ensure that the data you want is getting saved.  Then, when the page is loaded, fetch the data and populate the form as you see fit.